# Passing the value and color of the text in a cell to a user defined function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-udf

Currently I am experiencing issues with passing the value of a cell and its respective text color to my user defined function. I am passing the references as ranges and using .Font.ColorIndex. This is then used in a IF statement to determine if any are red (value of 3) and then application.caller.fontIndex=3 to turn the cell text red.

```
 Public Function Example(AA As Range, BB As Range) As double
 Dim AAcolor, BBcolor As Integer
 AAcolor=AA.font.colorindex
 BBcolor=BB.font.colorindex
 IF BBcolor=3 Or AAcolor=3 Then
  Application.caller.font.colorIndex=3
 End If
```

The rest of the code is simply formulas that calculate a double from the ranges inputted which is returned as a double.

To clarify, I am trying to determine the color of the text of the referenced input cells. I am not limited to a UDF to do this if I can call the sub from my UDF.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel   UDF can only return a value - it cannot update the worksheet directly.

Comment: workaround : ... assuming that data is in cell C5  ....  run a UDF in cell B5 "_=Example(C5)_" , that takes value of C5, and returns a 3  .... do conditional format on C5 to go red if  "_=B5 = 3_"

Comment: The application.caller.font.colorindex=3 changes the font color of the cell C5. Is it possible to nest a Sub to determine the font color from the given range?

Answer (score 0):

proof of concept ...

try this ... use F5 or F8 to step through "sub abc123" and watch K5 on worksheet ( I5 is just to supply a variable to the UDF )

it is from a recorded macro, so it is kind of convoluted

note: use another UDF in another cell if you want to do more stuff

```
Sub abc123()

    ' run on empty worksheet

    Rows("5:5").Delete

    Range("K5").FormulaR1C1 = "56.7"                                         ' just some random data
    Range("K5").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=J5=3"   ' conditional format dependent on value of J5
    Range("K5").FormatConditions(Range("K5").FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Range("K5").FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = -16776961
    Range("K5").FormatConditions(1).Font.TintAndShade = 0
    Range("K5").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Range("J5").FormulaR1C1 = "=example(RC[-1])" ' UDF returns value to J5
    Stop
    Range("I5").FormulaR1C1 = "2"                ' just some values passed to UDF
    Stop
    Range("I5").FormulaR1C1 = "3"                ' this one should make K5 go red
    Stop
    Range("I5").FormulaR1C1 = "4"

End Sub


Public Function Example(a As Variant) As Variant     ' UDF
    Example = a                                      ' just echo back the value that was received
End Function
```

Comment: What the OP wants to do cannot be done from within a UDF...

Comment: `Application.Caller` for a UDF returns a reference to the calling cell, so the OP's syntax is correct but (as Tim said) the code won't work anyway.

Comment: learn something new every day ... lol

Comment: The udf colors the text fine. I don't see the issue with using a udf. I am not trying to change the color of the whole cell.